# Laravel 5 Pagination how to Render Result in another Page

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-5

Hi I made a Laravel Project which I can view some records with sorting. For examle I have a deliveries page with URL

```
http://localhost/dboard/public/deliverytracker
```

In that form there are From Date and To Date to sort out the data before the query.
When I clicked submit the data is rendered and the pagination links is there. However when click, for example page 2 of the pagination which is

```
http://localhost/dboard/public/deliverytracker?page=2
```

in the link it won't rendered the page 2 of the data. It just reloaded the page where I need to select again the from date and to date then clicking submit again. Did I missed something?

Here's my route

```
/* Delivery Tracker */
Route::get('deliverytracker', 'DeliveryTrackerController@deliveryIndex');
Route::post('deliverytracker', 'DeliveryTrackerController@getDeliveries');
```

My function when I submit the form

```
public function getDeliveries()
{
    $rules = array(
        'fromdate'  => 'required',
        'todate'    => 'required',
    );

    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

    // Check if all fields is filled
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        return Redirect::to('deliverytracker')->withErrors($validator);
    }
    else
    {
        $from   = Input::get('fromdate');
        $to     = Input::get('todate');

        $deliveries = new DeliveryTracking();
        $result = $deliveries->getDeliveries($from, $to);

        // Get the current page from the url if it's not set default to 1
        $page = Input::get('page', 1); 

        // Number of items per page
        $perPage = 5;

        // Start displaying items from this number;
        $offSet = ($page * $perPage) - $perPage; // Start displaying items from this number

        // Get only the items you need using array_slice (only get 10 items since that's what you need)
        $itemsForCurrentPage = array_slice($result, $offSet, $perPage, true);

        // Return the paginator with only 10 items but with the count of all items and set the it on the correct page
        $result =  new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($result), $perPage, $page);
        $result->setPath('deliverytracker');

        return view('deliverytracker.index')->with(array('result' => $result));

    }

}
```

My view

```
<div class="panel-body">
                @if(isset($result))
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Delivery Status</td>
                            <td>Ref. Number</td>
                            <td>PO #</td>
                            <td>Count</td>
                            <td>Delivery QTY</td>
                            <td>Date Delivered</td>
                            <td>Filename</td>
                            <td>Invoice #</td>
                            <td>Date Invoice</td>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($result as $key => $value)
                        @if($value->stat == "Completed")
                            <tr>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->stat  }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->oc }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->pon }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->cnt }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->dq }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->dd }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->fn }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->inum }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-success">{{ $value->di }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @elseif($value->stat == "Active")
                            <tr>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->stat  }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->oc }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->pon }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->cnt }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->dq }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->dd }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->fn }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->inum }}</td>
                                <td class="bg-danger">{{ $value->di }}</td>
                            </tr>   
                        @endif

                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                     </table>
                        {!! $result->render() !!}
                @else 
                    No records found.    

                @endif
 </div>
```

Comment: where do you set your fromdate and todate; because you made them required and they are not added to the URL for the other pages, you get redirected: see [Appending To Pagination Links](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view)

Answer (score 0):

In your post you mention that the second page is called using only `?page=N`, seeing your route is defined with both `GET` and `POST` you will hit the route definition for `GET` when clicking the next page **link**.

The pages buttons are simply links and not POST forms. So instead of hitting the `getDeliveries()` you are hitting `deliveryIndex()`.

Also you might consider appending the fromdate and todate to your pagination links; see [Appending To Pagination Links](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/pagination#displaying-results-in-a-view)

Comment: Ye, I'm trying your suggestion I think it is on appending the fromdate and todate. But how? my fromdate and todate is in the same form where i render the paginated result deliverytracker.index

Comment: I'm tried this, {!! $result->appends(['fromdate' => '2012-06-01', 'todate' => '2015-06-16'])->render() !!}  is that a correct format? I'll hardcode the fromdate and todate for a while then when it's ok I'll pass it from a controller.

Comment: you route get to a different route than post; that is something you have to check too. I can't see what the `deliveryIndex()` does, so can't assist you with it

Comment: deliveryIndex() only does this return view('deliverytracker.index'); So I need to create another route and controller for the pagination links?

Comment: the get request should also point to the `getDeliveries()` method, otherwise the request with `?page=N&todate=N&fromdate=N` will not hit the paginator class.

Answer (score 0):

Form fields(fromdate, todate) are not automatically attached to the pagination. You need to add query string values to paginator using ->append() method.

```
// Return the paginator with only 10 items but with the count of all items and set the it on the correct page
$result =  new LengthAwarePaginator($itemsForCurrentPage, count($result), $perPage, $page);
$result->setPath('deliverytracker');
$result->appends(['fromdate' => $from, 'todate' => $todate]);
```

Reference:
http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/Paginator.html#method_appends